# ClickOnce App unable to load DLL Even Though It Is Present

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

I have a 64 bit desktop written in C# using Visual Studio 2015 and deployed with ClickOnce. It relies on SQLite and I have included the `SQLite.Interop.dll` file in the publish using the following lines in the start-up project:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>true</ContentSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CopySQLiteInteropFiles>false</CopySQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CleanSQLiteInteropFiles>
    <CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>false</CollectSQLiteInteropFiles>
</PropertyGroup>
```

This appears to work and I can verify that the two copies of `SQLite.Interop.dll` are indeed deployed to subfolders called `x86` and `x64`. However some users still get the `Unable to load DLL SQLite.Interop.dll: The specified module could not be found` error message.

What's weird is that I copied the contents of my development bin folder and put it on the the deployment machine (in a different location) and it ran fine.

Is there some "DLL Hell" issue whereby different paths are searched for dependencies when an app is deployed using ClickOnce?

Comment: Looks like it is using a COM version of SQLite.  Even though the files may be installed by ClickOnce, I don't believe ClickOnce performs COM registration during installation which is possibly the cause of the problem you are encountering.

Comment: Interesting. Are you suggesting that Windows is finding and using an x86 version registered in the GAC rather than using the local copies I deploy with my app? Does this explain why it works when I run the app from a copy of the bin folder rather than installed by ClickOnce? Is there a way to overcome the use of GAC binaries?

Comment: No.  How did you reach that conclusion?  GAC has nothing to do with COM.  By the way, there are two GACs, one x86 and the other x64 (assuming it is a 64 bit OS) and the one that is used is determined by the bitness of the process - so that wouldn’t be the cause in any event.

Comment: So any suggestions on a solution please @MickyD?

Comment: Refer to my first comment

Comment: Still unable to fix. @MickyD can you suggest a solution please? I believe you're right that some other software has registered a different version of SQLite using COM. I just don't know how to overcome this.

Comment: OK I just noticed too that it ran for you when you _"copied the contents of my development bin folder"_.   It's possible that it might be simply a case that ClickOnce is not picking up indirect dependencies.  I've seen that before.  In your project settings; ClickOnce; click the button for deployment files and "tick" any other dependency that ClickOnce did not initially include.  Then run a deployment and compare the files deployed vs your **bin** folder.  Rinse and repeat until all files are deployed.